# I want to solve the screen transition problem using this "v-if"

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, vue.js, ionic-framework

// template

```
    <div class="login_div" v-if="pagenumber === '1'">
            <ion-buttons value="button" v-model="pagenumber">
                <ion-button>button without value</ion-button>
                <ion-button color="warning" fill="solid" expand="block" size="large" value="2">2 page</ion-button>
            </ion-buttons>
        </div>

        <div class="login_div" v-else-if="pagenumber === '2'">
            <ion-buttons value="button" v-model="pagenumber">
                <ion-button>button without value</ion-button>
                <ion-button color="warning" fill="solid" expand="block" size="large" value="3">3 page</ion-button>
            </ion-buttons>
        </div>

        <div class="login_div" v-else-if="pagenumber === '3'">
            <ion-buttons value="button" v-model="pagenumber">
                <ion-button>button without value</ion-button>
                <ion-button color="warning" fill="solid" expand="block" size="large" value="1">1 page</ion-button>
            </ion-buttons>
        </div>

        <div v-else>
            <ion-text>error page</ion-text>
        </div>
```

// script

```
    <script>
      import { IonToolbar, IonTitle, IonText, IonButtons, IonButton } from '@ionic/vue'

      export default ({
         components: { IonToolbar, IonTitle, IonText, IonButtons, IonButton },
         setup() {
            return {
                pagenumber: '1',
            }
         },
      })
    </script>
```

It's my first time asking a question to stackoverflow.

Above the code, I want to solve this problem that why don't the Vue's not change.

I try to follow the other code in the example of 'v-if', but code doesn't work.

How can I solve this problem? Please...THX

Comment: I am not sure this is right way to use v-if. Are you sure the pagenumber change when click that buttons? Also you should check your html. Tags inside of element... what you want do here I can't understand really.

Comment: Maybe I'm sure I'm missing something on how to use v-if, Could you please tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is not how you are using v-if to show a div depending on the value of `pagenumber` but how you are using the button components:

- `<v-buttons>` is just a container, it does not make sense to put a v-model attribute to it.
- You cannot assign a value to a `<v-button>` component.

Try changing the value of `pagenumber` on the click events of each button, like so:

```
<div class="login_div" v-if="pagenumber === '1'">
  <ion-button color="warning" fill="solid" expand="block" size="large" @click="pagenumber = '2'">2 page</ion-button>
</div>
<div class="login_div" v-else-if="pagenumber === '2'">
  <ion-button color="warning" fill="solid" expand="block" size="large" @click="pagenumber ='3'">3 page</ion-button>
</div>
...
```

Comment: thank you for your reply ;-)
This question is old and solved. When I asked this question, I did not understand the concept of ref.